# How can I get python library help in vim?

Tags: vimscript-python

I tried python-mode, it seems that it can work when I press <kbd>K</kbd> on "numpy.array", but if I want to press <kbd>K</kbd> on "np.array", it won't work.

Comment: That's because `np` is not the name of a module itself; it is a variable defined within the program to be another name for an already existing module.  Therefore, you cannot find help on it without actually running the program.

Comment: @zondo I understand. If there's a way like vim help command, let me able to do :help(numpy.array). Or do you have some suggestions?

Comment: You could use `:!pydoc numpy.array`

Comment: @zondo, thanks! I don't need to google usage every time.

Comment: It's a pleasure!  For more information, try `:help :!` from within Vim.  You might also find `man pydoc` from the terminal to be interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) plugin.  It uses [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) to get completions and is much better at doing so than python-rope is.  It will resolve `np.array` to `numpy.array` and show the appropriate documentation in a tab/split.  Be warned that numpy is notoriously slow for Jedi to resolve when it's not cached.

zondo's suggestion to use `:!pydoc numpy.array` does work, but I find it annoying because I can't use Vim mappings to navigate the output, yank text from it, or leave it open for reference.  There's also the issue of using a virutalenv, which may not have `pydoc` in the virtualenv's `$PATH`.  In that case, you would have to use: `:!python -m pydoc numpy.array`.

Comment: That's pretty cool.